# Transferring from hidden MySQL to Amazon RDS

Tags: ssh, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a database on my old web host. They have a MySQL server that is only accessible to their network. I have SSH access to my hosting server, so I can run the MySQL command there.

Is there a way using SSH tunnelling I could use Amazon DMS to migrate a database from the hosting MySQL server to Amazon RDS?

I tried using SSH port forwarding to forward MySQL traffic from an EC2 instance to the hosting server then on to the hidden MySQL server but I couldn't ever get a connection. It always timed out.

Comment: Just run an export and import the data on the amazon side?

Comment: I was able to do it that way, but I'm looking for a more automated manner to do it on live db's. DMS can sync the database live.

Comment: You're migrating anyway. You will most likely have to take down the service anyway. Shutdown the service, export, import, restart. If they took measures to prevent outside communications don't try to needlessly circumvent it or talk to them to maybe allow communication with your new system. As for your setup you would need a connection that works both ways and not just one way. As you said they setup their server to communicate only with their servers ... your EC2 instance probably is not part of it.

Comment: *I tried using SSH port forwarding to forward MySQL traffic from an EC2 instance to the hosting server then on to the hidden MySQL server but I couldn't ever get a connection.*  You need to keep trying.  If you have both A >> ssh >> B and then B >> mysql-proto >> C connectivity, then you should have all the necessary components, you just need to get the SSH setup correct. What command did you use to try to build the tunnel, and then how did you test it?  Consider editing the question.  Done correctly, the remote MySQL will be accessible on the local EC2 machine's TCP port 3306.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Database Migration Service probably isn't worth using. It [doesn't transfer](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/rds-to-ec2-migration-mysql/) indexes or properties like auto_increment. I migrated RDS to EC2 hosted MySQL and it made a massive mess that took me a long time to [manually fix](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/fixing-wordpress-indexes-foreign-keys-and-auto_increment-fields/).

I suggest mysqldump and a load is a better approach. Once you've done that you could potentially use DMS to keep the data in the database up to date, though I'm not 100% sure it will do that for you. MySQL native replication is probably a better approach, there's a [guide for that here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.NonRDSRepl.html).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for zero downtime methods of transferring on websites that's that are actively updating database info so native replication might be a better way.

Comment: For zero downtime you'll want to dump, import, replicate, then change the app to point at the new database.